# Is a contraction idempotent operator self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is a contraction idempotent operator self-adjoint?

In the other words, if $T:H\to H$ is a bounded linear operator such that $||T||\leq1$ and $T^{2}=T$, can we conclude $T=T^*$?

Comment: Any attempts? Your thoughts?

Comment: I tried to solve this problem so much, but all of my attempts yielded nothing.
I solve it when T is one-to-one operator, but probably all contraction idempotent operators are not one-to-one.

Comment: It seems that $T=T^*$ is in general false. See the canonical decomposition in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_%28operator_theory%29 where the unitary operator $U$ need not be self-adjoint.

Comment: $T^2 = T$ means $T$ is a _projection_. A projection is self-adjoint if and only if it is an orthogonal projection. $T = 0$ is trivial, and otherwise, one has $\lVert P\rVert \geqslant 1$ for all projections $P\neq 0$. So the question is, can you show that a projection with norm $1$ is an orthogonal projection?

Comment: In my textbooks a projection is self-adjoint by the definition. Also by a theorem in [Tsoy-Wo](http://www.amazon.com/Banach-Hilbert-Spaces-Vector-Measures-Representations/dp/9812380388/ref=asap_B001JOE8T0_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1417507970&sr=1-1) if T is a projection we have either $||T||=0$ or $||T||=1$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a proof.

Note that $\|T^*\|=\|T\|\leq1$. For an $x\in H$, $\langle Tx,T^*x\rangle=\langle T^2x,x\rangle=\langle Tx,x\rangle$. Then
\begin{align}
\|Tx-T^*x\|^2&=\|Tx\|^2+\|T^*x\|^2-2\text{Re}\,\langle Tx,T^*x\rangle\\
&\leq\|Tx\|^2+\|x\|^2-2\text{Re}\,\langle Tx,x\rangle\\ &=\|Tx-x\|^2.
\end{align}
If we now take $x=Ty$ for some $y\in H$, we have $Tx=x$, and so $T^*x=Tx$, which translates to $$T^*Ty=TTy=Ty.$$ This shows that $T^*T=T$. Then $T^*=(T^*T)^*=T^*T=T$. So $T$ is selfadjoint (actually, it is positive).