# Non-orthogonal bounded linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We have the following theorem :

> Let $P:H\to H$ be a bounded linear map on a complex vector space satisfying $P^2=P$. Then the following are equivalent:
>   $(1)$ $P$ is self-adjoint $(2)$ $P$ is normal $(3)$ $x-Px$ is orthogonal to $Px$ for every $x\in H$. Also, if these conditions hold then $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto its image.

Now I was trying to find a linear bounded map that satisfies none of these, but failed to do so. What would be an easy to see example of such a map that is not orthogonal projection? (The reason I stated the theorem is because now we know that it is equivalent to find such a map that is not self-adjoint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $$P=\begin {bmatrix} 1&1\\0&0\end {bmatrix}. $$ By "putting more zeroes" you can generalize this idea to any $H $ with $\dim h\geq2$.

Comment: By bounded I mean $||Pv||\le||v||$. That is the standard definition right? Why is this bounded?

Comment: @UserNotFound In a finite dimensional vector space, every linear operator is bounded

Comment: @Stefan Is it easy to see? My knowledge in these fields is limited.

Comment: @UserNotFound: Boundedness is equivalent to continuity. Do you know that every linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space is continuous?

Comment: @Stefan Yes I know that....ok let me just ask the question and you say yes or no: "$P$ is an operator on a complex vector space satisfying $P^2
= P$ and $||P v|| \le ||v||$ for all $v$". I wanted to show that $P$ need not be an orthogonal projection. Are we on the same page?

Comment: @UserNotFound: if $P^2=P$ and $\|P\|\leq1$, then $P$ is an orthogonal projection.See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047952/is-a-contraction-idempotent-operator-self-adjoint).

Comment: @UserNotFound: the answers and comments at Math.SE are not the right place for a class on Functional Analysis, and I think you need to learn chapter 1, section 1 of any text on operators on a normed space. The assertion "$\|Pv\|\leq\|v\|$ for all $v$" is exactly the same as "$\|P\|\leq1$". And it is more than "bounded", which would be "$\|Pv\|\leq c\,\|v\|$ for a fixed $c$ and all $v$".

Answer (score 0):

Try an oblique projector (from Carl Meyer's *Matrix Analysis and Linear Algebra*)

$$P := \begin{pmatrix} -2 & -2 & -1 \\ 3 & 3 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
is an idempotent (i.e., $P^2 = P$) but clearly $P$ is not self-adjoint.