# an equivalent condition for a projection on a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, projection, idempotents

A mapping $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is said to be a linear operator if $T(\alpha x + y) = \alpha T(x) + T(y)$ for any element $x , y \in H$ and every complex number $\alpha$. We define the operator norm as follows:

$\|T\| = \inf \{ c>0 : \| T(x) \| \ge c \|x\| \}$,

also this norm is defined with

$\| T\| = \sup \{ \| T(x) \| : \|x\| = 1 \} = \sup \{ \| T(x) \| : \|x\| \le 1 \} = \sup \{ | <T(x) ,y> | : \|x\| = \|y\| = 1 \} $.

The operator $T$ is called projection if $T$ is idempotent and hermitian, i.e. $T^2 = T$ and $T^* = T$ respectively. Now I want to show that :

> If $T$ is idempotent and $\|T\| \le 1$ then $T$ is a projection.

In fact I have to show that $T=T^*$ but I can't prove it. Please say me how can I say $T=T^*$ ?

Comment: By idempotent you mean $T^2=T$, correct?

Comment: Yes; idempotent property is that $T^2=T$.

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047952/is-a-contraction-idempotent-operator-self-adjoint

Comment: Really thanks; it was a great answer!